# How to call variable from layout in view in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a variable in layout file like this

```
$bmodal =array(
        'data-target'   =>  '#myModal',
        'data-toggle'   =>  'modal'
    );
```

I want to call `$bmodal` in a link in a view file to optimize the code
How can i do that?
Any one can help?
Thanks

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Please do not use tags for 3 different versions; if your question is version specific use the tag for the one version you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through a helper, you can make your own helper in which you can pass the variable in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Views are rendered before layouts so you can not.

Comment: ok, i want to optimize that code, how can i do that?    echo $this->Manager->link(
      __($donateCounts)
      ,array(
       'action' => "admin_view_donator"
       ,$rows['DonationSite']['donation_site_id']
       )
      ,array(
       'data-target' => "#myModal",
       'data-toggle' => "modal"
       ) 
      );

Comment: Use [helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)